# Best way to run server-side rendering only once in Nextjs

Tags: static, next.js, rendering, server-side-rendering, server-side

I have an app that will use Javascript for data-handling. I only need one single server call and would like it to be done in a SSR Page as the data call on the client takes awhile.

How would this be properly done today?

I have actually tried almost everything I could come up with online and couldn't find a proper solution. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use getStaticProps, which would load the API once.

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: But the idea is to have the app reload the current server data each for each visitor. The data on the server changes daily. Would this have been the solution all along?

Comment: To clarify, you want the data to reload every time the user opens the page? I can edit the question if that is the case.

Comment: export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({ store }) => {
    return { props: { null }, revalidate: 10 }
})

Comment: So the above is working as Ive been hoping (logic removed).